# Should I write up my employee again or fire her

Tags: discipline

I’m a store manager at a retail outlet mall and recently , my assistant store manager came to me that she and who I will call employee A were talking about gay rights. Within that conversation, employee A stated that employee B made her uncomfortable a year prior because employee B made a comment that the idea of same-sex relationships are weird. Also, in that conversation was another person, who I will call employee C. I was shocked and horrified by this revelation and asked my assistant why neither employee A and C came to me right away about this highly inappropriate discussion. My assistant store manager told me that employee B made both employee A and C horribly scared of working with B, even though A and B closed multiple times together, that they're scared for their life and that must've been why they didn't say anything until a year later, employee A had been ruminating about the event since a year ago, and that employee B must've gotten up in their faces and intimidated A and C to not speak up.

Because of my training as a store manager, I’m supposed to take every harassment complaint seriously and investigate the claims because I'm legally required to. If not, me and my assistant manager can be fired from the company for knowing about this incident and not doing anything about it. I talk to my DM because I've never dealt with this before. He yelled at me that me and my assistant manager that we aren't doing our jobs properly because we should've known this conversation took place, and that this shouldn't be happening. I talk to employee A, who confirms the allegations, but she kept telling us that it happened a year ago, that she's over it, and that it's nothing and the assistant manager didn't have her consent to report it.

I then call employee C who gave me more information that employee B asked employee C's views on the political landscape and asked if C believed in God. Unfortunately, neither employee A and C made it known to employee B that the behavior was making them uncomfortable, there was no repeated discussions after this incident, employee B doesn’t have a record of anything and has been a stellar employee, I spoke to all my other employees and no one has said that employee B say anything harassing since then or before, employee B has treated everyone kindly and friendly, this incident occurred a year prior, and with that, it wouldn't fall under legal harassment according to harassment laws federally and in the employee handbook.

Even though the behavior and incident are a one-off, I still find it totally inappropriate to discuss politics at work and ask if someone believes in God (!), and employee B should know better than to ask and start this type of discussion. I'm also so angry that employee B made both A and C scared for their lives that they couldn't bring this up until a year later. I must protect them from employee B since B must've intimidated them in some way. I then write employee B up for harassment, even though it doesn’t fit in the legal definition of harassment. My DM said not to fire B, but just tell her the conversation was inappropriate and not write her up. However, my assistant manager said that we should document it because even if your boss tells you to do something, you have to cover yourself, especially with harassment claims. **In addition, it's employee B's fault for making both A and C scared to report her**, so I tell everyone in the store to watch over her and tell me what she does wrong. Anyhow, I write up B to make sure she doesn't do it again. The write up contains: In late January of 2023, the associate had an inappropriate conversation with 2 associates about her views on sexual orientation and asked an associate about her religious beliefs. These conversations made the associates uncomfortable. Employee B's actions are in violation of the companies policy regarding harassment. Employee B will be asked to review the policy Against Harassment and sign the acknowledgment form as well as this document.

I then go to employee B, tell her what happened, and she admits to the allegations. Then fast forward three weeks later, on Monday, one my sales leads comes up to me and tells me that the day before that employee B told employee A that she can't discuss speculating other people's sexuality and talking about sex acts because that is sexual harassment. Then employee A comes up to me and tells me her concerns that employee B is massively overstepping. Employee B goes to two other sales associates and says on the sales floor that they shouldn't be discussing inappropriate topics on the sale floor, and she says this in front of customers. Everyone came up to me with concerns that they'll be written up for harassment, and I have to say to them that they won't and they have nothing to be afraid about because they haven't done or said anything wrong.

Employee B is seriously overstepping her boundaries by ordering people because she isn't a sales lead and isn't a manager. I'm thinking to myself, do I have to write her up again to stop her from harassing her coworkers? I'm at the end of my rope with this associate. Should I fire her?

Edit: my assistant and I spoke to B and asked her why she did what she did. Employee B stated that many employees, including A, have inappropriate workplace conversations that border on sexual harassment. She also wanted to tell everyone that they don't need to be scared of her to tell her when she says something that makes someone uncomfortable, instead of running to us to speak on their behalf.

My assistant and I ask what inappropriate conversations A and other associates have and she says that A speculates about other people's sexuality because she enjoys picking up someone's sexuality "vibes" and has spoken about anal sex on the sales floor. Two other associates, who are half brother and sister, speak about their family and relationship trauma in the fitting room with customers around. One had an abusive boyfriend and told B she was raped on the sales floor and the other associate was friends with that person's abusive boyfriend and was in his room (B says she doesn't recall if the statement was sexual or not and that I would have to go to the associate for clarification). B then also states that she wanted to go to every single employee who did this because the legal definition of harassment means that the behavior has to be unwanted. For the behavior to be unwanted, she wanted to make it clear to them verbally that what they say is not appropriate (because she has learned what she did was wrong and bad) and wanted to educate her peers and sales lead. In addition, she wanted to tell them that if there are any further conversations about those topics she would hear on or off the sales floor to her or in earshot, that she would report them to HR for harassment. B also stated that people aren't mind readers and people must speak up when they're uncomfortable. B also apologized to A for making her uncomfortable.

My assistant and I are then in such shock that these people would say such things. B added that they talk inappropriate topics when the assistant and I are and aren't around, and that's because we're mainly at the register and not in the fitting room. I then tell B that I won't write her up or fire her, but I gave her a strong warning that she shouldn't be overstepping and ordering people around (especially since A is a sales lead) and go to management first, so we can deal with it.

Comment: The decision is yours, hence your title manager-boss. Although I find it a bit melodramatic that someone at work is afraid for their life.  What country are we talking about.

Comment: Have you asked _YOUR_ manager how to handle this? Have you looked at company policy on where lines should be drawn in the workplace? Seems to me you are not only making a mountain out of a molehill, but setting off fireworks on top and likely to start an avalanche. And I'm heavily liberal. (And, literally, a card-carrying member of the ACLU just so I can use that phrase.)

Comment: "made her uncomfortable... they're scared for their life... employee B has treated everyone kindly and friendly" That middle beat is a _wild_ jump. Can you give more detail on what the supposed, specific threat was? It's such a huge gap in the story, I think a lot of readers here are going to be skeptical that this is even real.

Comment: There was a conversation one year ago and today this is made such a problem? Your DM yells at you because you don't constantly listen to what your employees talk to each other? Honestly... all that is happening between adult people? I don't share B's opinion, but I don't see the drama in just stating something appears "weird". What did really happen?

Comment: _it's employee B's fault for making both A and C scared to report her_  -This makes no sense. It's not employee B's fault that A and C are hypersensitive. Based on the **hearsay** reported here, B engaged in no harassment whatsoever.

Comment: _employee B must've gotten up in their faces...A and C to not speak up_ - **Wild jump here**: Maybe A and C came up with a scheme to cause trouble for B, because they didn't like B's POV, and figured they could make some trouble for B - quite a common occurrence these days -news and social media cause people to hatch nefarious schemes targeting those with opinions that don't conform to the contemporary _mainstream_ , to the point that many states are now passing laws forbidding **viewpoint discrimination**. As @TheDemonLord mentioned, taking action against B may put you in legal jeopardy.

Comment: hmmm.. So you told B what is /is not appropriate to talk about at work... And wrote B up for it. Then B starts making sure that everyone else to follow the standards that you set... And you are mad at B because of that? SO its one rule for people who's POV is different from your own. And another rule for everyone else. That is discrimination and legally actionable... Check yourself before you wreck yourself.

Answer (score 9):

One viewpoint of a conversation a year ago is not cause for a write up. It's cause for finding more info or wondering what the late agenda is.

When I have had situations like this I want to hear from all concerned before anything else, and since it's a year gone by the details might not be remembered. I'd be more concerned that employees feel their lives are threatened, yet haven't said a word for a year. That sounds overly dramatic at best.

Comment: I'd be more concerned that employees SAY they feel their lives are threatened, yet (etc.) That's one hell of an accusation. Most human beings are able to disagree without being murderous, or even homicidally negligent. Most employees worth retaining can find ways to work with someone they don't especially like. There is something going on that does not appear in the problem statement, and it is completely unclear who's overreacting.

Comment: _Most human beings are able to disagree without being murderous, or even homicidally negligent_  **Nowhere** is it mentioned that B actually did anything _murderous_ - only that A and C felt that way. The problem is with A and C - who are obviously either hypersensitive or up to no good.

Answer (score 2):

**To address the question directly**

I don't think you have grounds to fire anyone. In fact, based on some reading on this - I think **YOU** may have broken the law.

I'm going to presume a couple of things about Employee B - they are probably religious and probably hold religious views on Sex and Sexuality. I'm also fairly certain that given your descriptions - that everyone is in their late teens and early twenties.

Now - the first problem you have is one that is mostly not your fault, that is - there are people who cannot accept people having a difference of opinion on certain topics. I could list them, but this post will be contentious enough without.

Said people feel that disagreeing with them is violence and 'Genocide' (I wish I was joking, but I have heard this phrasing) - Employees A and C sound very much like they are of this ilk.

Onto the facts of the matter - in the space of a year - you have 2 conversations, some additional behavior and other items:

Conversation 1: Employee B says "the idea of same-sex relationships are weird." In order to get from what seems to be merely a stated opinion 'I think X is strange' to Harassment "You are bad because you like X" is missing a step or two.

Behavior:

> employee B has treated everyone kindly and friendly, this incident occurred a year prior, and with that, it wouldn't fall under legal harassment according to harassment laws federally and in the employee handbook

And this is your next major issue - If I say 'I think *issue-du-jour* is weird' but I still *by my actions* treat everyone equally and kindly, as you say not meeting the legal threshold for harassment

Conversation 2:

> I then call employee C who gave me more information that employee B asked employee C's views on the political landscape and asked if C believed in God.

Yeah... You may want to seriously read up on Title 7 of the Civil Rights act. The one that guarantees Religious Freedom.

As I understand the law (IANAL) - if you allow any informal discussions at work either in a Break Room or similar public forum that are not Work related (and I can guarantee you that you do) - then *you cannot prohibit a discussion about Politics or Religion*

[Here is a good discussion on the issue](https://www.yeremianlaw.com/employment/can-you-be-fired-for-talking-about-religion-at-work/) - If Employee B was proselytizing or *regularly* discussing Religion with Employees *who had asked her to stop* - then you might have a case - but 2 conversations in a year? Good luck. You telling her she *can't* talk about Religion is quite possibly in breach of Title 7.

Finally the 'Overstepping the boundary' - So, you've penalized her for having non-work conversations at work and her response is to make sure people don't have non-work related conversations at work.

See - what's she's done is **exactly** what the law says - if you say no non-work related conversations at work, that means **all** non-work related conversations at work.

If, however, you meant *I don't want these Political and Religious subjects that I don't like discussed at work* - then I hope Employee B sees this post and sues you and the company into oblivion for violation of her Civil Rights.

In short - I think you've got some young woke employees who subscribe to the ridiculous idea that if someone disagrees with you, they are a threat to your life. You have another employee who has by their actions demonstrated they aren't discriminating anyone *despite holding a different, and by all accounts, sincere viewpoint that may be religiously based* - and your actions *already* may have breached the Civil Rights act.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there were no two conversations. The two topics were discussed in 1 conversation.however, political discussions are OK if people agree.

Comment: "political discussions are OK if people agree." - This remark *alone* convinces me that anything *you* try to do about this problem is only going to make it worse.

Comment: I heartily detest the term "woke"; it's heavily abused. But expressing an opinion or asking a question politely, once, is not harrassment. You've given us nothing to work with to understand why the other employees might be afraid.  I'm not sure I agree that management's response is legally actionable -- but it seems to be way out of proportion to the issue. "I find it weird" is not disparagement, it's purely personal reaction, and as long as they aren't letting that influence their behavior toward others it's completely irrelevant except possibly as a chance to educate them.

Comment: Political discussions are OK if people agree to discuss. Ditto religious. If they don't agree, one can walk away. If the other continues to pester them, THAT can be harrassment. The Jehovah's Witnesses showing up on my doorstep every few years are not harrassment, just annoyingly irrelevant.

Comment: +1 _You telling him he can't talk about Religion is quite possibly in breach of Title 7_

Comment: Apparently this truthful and excellent answer has been downvoted simply because of **viewpoint discrimination**.

Comment: @FrankHopkins - you are probably correct that was the intent, although perhaps not well expressed. Deleting that comment. Tnx.

Comment: Not surprised to see this answer heavily downvoted... Nice answer though you got your hes/shes mixed up (Employee B is women according to the Post)...

Comment: @Questor - Oops!

Answer (score 1):

It seems B is taking your negligence to properly investigate and ideally come to a mutual agreement without disciplinary measures around and turns it back on you and the team. When you rule by strict law, it's fair game to apply that strict law to everyone.

There is typically two ways of handling private talk in a team. Either they are homogenous enough or agree to disagree friendly on political, sexual etc. topics to have such conversations amongst themselves in the working place without that affecting them or the customer relationships OR you employ strict rules categorically on everyone. You went the strict rule route with B, so now they make sure everyone follows this strict rule approach. It will be hard to fall back to a more loose way to handle it by mutual tolerance instead. Now everyone needs to become professional all the time...

If you want to go back to a more loose handling, you would need to make both groups agree that some looseness and private talk is more fun than none and handle disagreements or taboo topics properly amongst themselves by talking to each others like grownups what they are fine discussing with colleagues and what not - and then respecting that. That is hard work however, now that the fronts are already hardened.

You basically have three ways

1. You fire B - ideally the others agree on their political and sexual stance that they can joke around as they like. This might cost you some customers if they indeed also don't respect their feelings and talk about intimate issues when customers are around. It is also pretty amoral, throwing B under the bus because they are a minority in your team. And B might have a legal angle to sue you, depending on the country you are in. But it is arguably the quickest short term solution (with negative consequences). Though the issue might reappear in different form.
2. You clearly announce the rules about harassment. What they mean in day to day life for your employees. How to announce what they don't want to be talked about. What cannot be talked about in general and what constitutes an offence in your view. Then you enforce these rules. Strictly and on everyone equally. After a while when everyone is sobered up a bit and annoyed you might try to loosen the screws a bit to get a better atmosphere going again, which leads us to 3)
3. You can try to take them all into a conversation about the topic and how you want to go on in the future regarding having private conversations at work. One is the strict approach from 2). Which will probably suck for them - most people enjoy when they can have relatively free conversations with their colleagues and be on friendly terms. So a compromise that is a bit more loose than 2) based on mutual respect might be beneficial for all. You don't enforce a "no private talk" policy and they respect each others limitations and limit their private talk to when customers are not around. You promise to not hawkishly microcontrol them, but that trust needs to be appreciated and if you hear anything in that regard again, strict rules with enforcement it is.